# How is ...등 used in a sentence?

Tags: vocabulary, word-usage

I've seen 등 inputted after listing something, and I think I understand what it means, but I can't find sentences showing what to write after that. How do I continue on the sentence after writing 등?

It would really help if you wrote a variety of sentences using 등 so I can get the gist of it.

Thanks!!

Comment: It means “et cetera” and you would probably want a subject marker (the entire list being a subject), an object marker (it being an object), or a comma (providing extra information on a group of things) with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some examples that show the usage of 등.

> 갑각류는 게, 가재, 새우, 따깨비 **등**의 절지동물을 말한다.
> Crustaceans mean arthropods such as
> crabs, lobsters, shrimps, barnacles and so on.
>
> 동남아시아는 아시아의 남동부를 지칭하며 베트남, 필리핀, 인도네시아, 태국 **등**의 나라를 포함한다.
> Southeast Asia refers to the Southeastern part of Asia which includes countries
> like Vietnam, The Philippines, Indonesia, Thailand, and so on.
>
> 홍수, 산불, 태풍 **등** 많은 천재지변이 발생하고 있다.
> A great number of natural disasters are occurring, including floods, forest fires, and typhoons.

The third example might be particularly interesting because it puts [홍수, 산불, 태풍 등] and [많은 천재지변] in an appositive relation.  등 is often used like this.  The other examples can also drop 의 after 등 this way, but unlike the third one, they seem to sound better with it included.

Comment: Like, the first two being _restrictive_ (by the particle “의”) and the other being not?

Comment: Yes, I suppose that might be the reason.

Comment: @user591415 thank you! This was very helpful :D

Answer (score 1):

등 mean "and so on" or "and or that"

for example
커피, 차 등이 점심식사로 제공될 것입니다.
coffee, tea and all that will be served for lunch

Comment: Ahh I get it now, thank you!